# Django development - how to lay out and use code properly

Tags: php, django, codeigniter

Hi i'm a PHP developer trying to convert to Django and im having a bit of a hard time understanding where to put things and how to use the new language. Basically what i want to know is for example in codeigniter i would make classes and functions in my controllers. Where do i do that in django?

I believe the 'view' in django is more like the controller in an MVC framework but all the examples i can find of the view are very simple and just call a template and pass it some data.

I currently have an index view and a 'rates' view in my current project. The index page will call rates via JS and pass it some GET variables. In my php version i used these to instantiate my rates class which when had all the needed functions in it. I want to do this in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it is called, "MVT" instead of "MVC" is that "View" to Django means, "presentation of data (according to given logic)" and "Template" means, "display of data presented." In a traditional MVC paradigm, "Controller" means "executer of logic" and "View" is "presentation of the result of the executed logic". (They are almost the same idea, but not quite).

So, what does this mean? Basically, if I were building something in Symfony, I would put all of the logic in the sfAction components. In CodeIgniter, it would be in the CI_Controller. In Django, I will place all of the logic in the "Views".

Just like CI (and Zend and others) will then call a "View" from the Controller descendant, the Django view will also call a "Template" from its "View". (Symfony's views are often called in a different syntax, so I will leave that to the reader to research if so desired).

---

Looking at your example, it looks like you want to call a method in the "View" (which view is configured in `urls.py`) which simply instantiates another object which has "all of your logic in it". Something like:

```
def ratesHandler(request):
    rate = MyRatesClass(request.GET)
    return HttpResponse("Insert something here. ") #or render_to_response
```

Comment: Ok that helps a lot thanks. Essentially all i am trying to do is take the GET params and use them to load data from a model, which is then used to calculate the 'rate' and return that to the user in the template.

I think i understand a bit better now how my view should look so thanks for that.

Comment: No problem. (If you can't tell, I'm a PHP developer who has done some work in Django -- figured you'd appreciate the analogies)

Comment: Yea that helps, I've been doing PHP dev work for the best part of 8 years now but I seem to be having a hard time getting my head around how to do things in python / Django that i could do in a matter of second in PHP :-)

Answer (score 0):

The logic always belongs in the view. You can put whatever logic you like there - no need to put it into a class, unless you want to. If the logic is related to a specific model, though, it is best to make it a method of the model or the model's Manager.

Answer (score 0):

In django: "models" go in `models.py`, "controllers" go in `views.py` and "views" go in templates.

Models tend to be classes that subclass `django.db.models.Model`

Controllers (in `views.py`) are often functions but you can use classes if you like.

Note that if you're just displaying data from the database you can often use [generic views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/) so you hardly have to do any coding at all.

I can't tell whether there is a question in the last 2 paragraphs of your post. If there is a question there, please edit your post so it's clear.

Comment: (As a note, while it is convention to have all of your models in `models.py` and your views in `views.py`, these are not strictly required -- if there are a large number of views or models, it might be easier to create a different module structure)

Comment: Nope no question, i was just trying to define what i think i know and what it is im trying to do.